# Is there any need to use patch:after with Unicorn configuration files

Tags: configuration, unicorn

I'm working in a Helix solution and have noticed things like:

```
<configuration name="Feature.MyModuleName"
               dependencies="Foundation.SomethingElse" 
               patch:after="configuration[@name='Foundation.Core']">
```

To me, the `dependencies` attribute seems like all you should need.

Is it really necessary `patch:after` *as well as* the `dependencies` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. At least potentially.

`patch:after` happens when `Sitecore.Configuration.Factory` reads and parses and constructs the object graph that the configuration represents. So at `Initialize` time of the application. There could be Foundation level configuration entries (like default serializer and so on) that need to be set up, before your Feature level configuration is read and parsed.

The `dependencies` attribute affects Unicorn sync order at *runtime*. So much much later in process/lifecycle of your application.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer. So in most cases, we should not need `patch:before`; only when there is something which changes the behaviour of serialization/unicorn.

Comment: Yes. Which in a typical Helix type setup would be something like Foundation.Serialization.